# MVC custom model binder issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, modelbinders, model-binding

I have a textbox in my view that i want to receive the value as a List of strings.

As example, if anybody enters: tag1,tag2,tag3... receive a List with 3 elements.

I did a custom model binder, but im still receiving from the post the string instead the List.

This is the stuff that i did:

**This is my Model:**

```
public class BaseItem
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
    public IList<string> RelatedTags
    {
       get;
       set;
    }

}
```

**My typed view with the model above:**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary("Please complete in a right way the fields below.") %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(e => e.Name)%>
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Name)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.Name)%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(e => e.RelatedTags)%>
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.RelatedTags)%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.RelatedTags)%>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
```

**My custom model binder:**

```
public class TagModelBinder:DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object GetPropertyValue(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext, 
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, 
        IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
       object value = base.GetPropertyValue(
                          controllerContext, 
                          bindingContext, 
                          propertyDescriptor, 
                          propertyBinder);
       object retVal = value;
       if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "RelatedTags")
       {                 
           retVal = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("RelatedTags")
                        .RawValue.ToString().Split(',').ToList<string>();
       }
       return retVal;
    }
}
```

I registered my Custom model binder on my Global.asax.cs file:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new TagModelBinder());
```

The issue that im having is that never enters in the method "GetPropertyValue" of my custom binder.

For sure im missing anything. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: Did you ever get a better answer for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding to typeof IList as that is the type you are trying to bind too.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IList<string>), new TagModelBinder());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Tarn, thanks for the response first of all.

It didnt work, but i thought that should be "typeof(string)" since i receive an string in the HttpRequest.Form["RelatedTags"].

Best Regards.

Jose

Comment: Actually all your HttpRequest.Form values will be strings. That's why you need to ModelBind them into other types, like a list of string :) You may have to write a binder for BaseItem if that is what you are trying to bind to in your action, I'm not sure the ASP.NET MVC model binder uses the custom model binders on properties like that, but I could be mistaken. Either way, typeof(string) is not correct.